# Display, keyboard, touch pad, and battery not working on Lenovo laptop

Tags: ubuntu, boot, keyboard, display, lenovo-laptop

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon laptop, about 1.5 years old. I use Ubuntu 20.04 on it. It used to work normally till yesterday, and I didn't do anything special before it stopped working properly. Now, when I start the laptop, the screen remains completely black, not even the Lenovo logo is showing on startup. Also the keyboard and touch pad are not working. Further, the laptop won't start unless the power cable is plugged in, even with a full battery.

However, when I connect an external monitor, external keyboard, and external mouse, I can use the laptop as normal (this is how I know the internal keyboard is not working in first place). I can enter the boot menu by pressing F12 on the external keyboard, but after that neither the external keyboard nor mouse works (and still not the built-in ones).

Do you think this can be a software issue, or will I have to send in the laptop and make use of the warranty? If yes, any ideas of what to try to resolve the problem? Please let me know if there's any more information I could provide which would be helpful. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 X1 Carbon ThinkPads here and I have taken the back cover off the older one to reset the battery.

Internal connections underneath the battery have gone bad in some way.

If you still have Warranty, contact Lenovo for repair instructions.

Otherwise get the machine serviced a a local dealer.

Comment: Thanks! Do I understand you correctly that you were having similar kinds of issues and found that it was due to faults in the wiring related to the battery?

Comment: The wiring is buried inside and the X1 is generally not user repairable.